# Action on Enriques surface by sections of Jacobian fibration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, k3-surfaces

A question about a statement in Shigeyuki Kondo's paper [Enriques surfaces with finite automorphism groups](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/math1924/12/2/12_2_191/_article):

The setup: Let $\pi: Y \to \mathbb{P}^1$  be a *special elliptic* pencil of *complex* Enriques surface $Y$. Ie general fiber of $\pi$ is smooth elliptic and *special* means that it has a $2$-section which is nodal curve (see Def 2.4 in the linked paper).

**Lemma 2.6** (p 199/200) states that if $X$ is the $2$-covering $K3$ surface of $Y$ there exist an elliptic pencil $J(\pi): J(Y) \to \mathbb{P}^1$ such that following diagram commutes (attention: it is *not(!)* neccessarily a pullback diagrm):

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>{p}  >> Y \\
@Vp'VV  @VV{\pi}V  \\
J(Y) @>{J(\pi)}>> \mathbb{P}^1
\end{CD}
$$

Moreover there is claimed in point (iv) that the group of sections of $J(\pi): J(Y) \to \mathbb{P}^1$ acts on $Y$ as automorphisms.

**Question:** How this action is concretely given/described? The paper claimes that it follows directly from construction. In not see how the construction of $J(Y)$ give natuarally rise for this mysterious action. Could somebody explain how this action by sections of $J(\pi)$  works in detail?

So far I can guess  the most intuitive/geometric pricture I can think of comes fiberwise, ie each "point" $s(b)$ of the section(= image of a point $b \in \mathbb{P}^1$ on the base under a section $s$ of $J(\pi)$) seems to gives a natural action on the corresp fiber $\pi^{-1}(b)$  as long as it lies in a fiber which is an elliptic curve. At least if *both* fibers over $b$ are isomorphic(!) ellipt curves. Firstly, is it a correct guess? (indeed, that appeared to be most"plausible" in this special situation)

Secondly, this seems that the way I tried to interpret it make a priori only sense on level of geometric points/ "variety style construction". How can this action be formalized in modern schmatic terms?

If that's exactly the action introduced above, how does it prolonges to singular fibers? (#UPDATE: This is ok now, by naf's explanation in the comments)

Comment: Since $Y$ is an Enriques surface, so minimal, any birational automorphism must actually be regular. Therefore to define the action it suffices to define it on the complement of the singular fibres.

Comment: alright, so having once defined the action on level of rational map it prolonges to "honest" action on whole surface. And just to clarify, my attempt above to give a geometric interpretation of this action at general fibers is correctly described, so far? Namely, is $s: \mathbb{P}^1 \to J(\pi)$ and $J(\pi)^{-1}(b), \pi^{-1}(b)$ are general fibers, ie elliptic surves, is then the action really given by "addition"/group law $(-)+s(b)$ fiberwise? If yes, don't we need to assure that for general $b \in \mathbb{P}^1$ the fibers  $J(\pi)^{-1}(b), \pi^{-1}(b)$ are canonically isomorphic?

Comment: I have not read the construction in the paper, but as it is mentioned in the remark after the lemma, this is an example of the general construction of Jacobian fibrations of an elliptic surface, so you could look up the reference there. Also, to get an action the fibres do not need to be canonically isomorphic, it suffices to have isomorphisms which are well-defined up to a translation.